# Product Images & Extensions not showing after Magento upgrade/migration

Tags: magento, migration, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

I upgraded my Magento from 1.5.1 to 1.7 using a fresh install as described here: http://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-development/upgrade/how-to-upgrade-magento/

For some reason my product images and extensions are not showing. I refreshed/flushed all caches, and reindexed.

Any idea why this might be?

I did run Magento/login to admin before copying the extension and media files over, but I am not sure if that should impact it.

Answer (score 0):

1) check /media and app/etc and /var folders permissions
2) check extensions list at  Admin - System - Configuration - Advanced
3) check if you can access some media image by direct url

let me know your results and I will try to help you based on results

Comment: Hi Tagan, Thanks for your comment.

1) I ran the Magento permissions script: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions  Then I flushed the cache, and still not working.
2) I do not see the extensions in the extensions list, except for a few that belong to a custom theme, which copied over successfully
3) I am able to access an image in the media folder by direct URL.
Please let me know if you have any ideas as to why it may not be working. Thanks for all your assistance

Comment: Maybe file app/etc/local.xml have flag disable_local_moulds enabled ?  Not sure what else I can suppose, but if you will give me access to server - I can rewiew all. Or you can try to enable magento logs and rewiew them